# My SQL - creating a grouped date list from database dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a view that list available dates from an online calendar (basically, I created entries for all available dates and then compare this to the dates that have been booked out - the view then show all dates within 'AvailableDates' where 'Date' <> 'BookedDate'.

So far I can get it to run a list that looks like this....

```
24th January 2014
7th February 2014
8th February 2014
```

....but this takes up a lot of space and the idea is that the list can be copied and pasted into an email/message for quick reference.

What I'm looking for is a way to group the dates so that the output looks like this...

```
Jan - 24th
Feb - 7th, 8th
```

...so that there is a maximum of 12 lines.

Could somebody tell me how to do this? - the field is a 'date' type.

Thanks,

Darren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have the year in there, too, or you might get false results.

```
SELECT 
YEAR(your_column) AS the_year, 
DATE_FORMAT(your_column, '%b') AS the_month_abbreviated, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(your_column, '%D') ORDER BY DAY(your_column) SEPARATOR ', ') AS the_days
FROM your_table
GROUP BY YEAR(your_column), DATE_FORMAT(your_column, '%b')
ORDER BY YEAR(your_column), MONTH(your_column)
```

- you can read more about the `DATE_FORMAT()` function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).
- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dcc4/8/0)</kbd>

Comment: One more thing on this.....the results show with months in alphabetical order (Apr, Aug, Dec etc) - how can I present them in month order?

Comment: add a `ORDER BY YEAR(your_column), MONTH(your_column)` after the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the datecolumn to month and use GROUP_CONCAT(). Maybe this can work or at least in the right direction.

```
SELECT  
LEFT(monthname(datecolumn),3),GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(datecolumn))
FROM table
GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(datecolumn),MONTH(datecolumn))
```

Missed to format the DAY. Now fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 MONTH(`d`),
 GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(`d`))
FROM
 a
GROUP BY
 YEAR(`d`),
 MONTH(`d`)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3dcc4/4)